# Java Swing recolor check box to appear disabled, without disabling it

Tags: java, swing

I am using programing in java with netbeans. Basically i am trying to allow the user to see that the check box is not being used. But allow them to click it if they want to use it again.

If i disable the check box then the user can not re-enable it by clicking so instead i want to merely *show* that it is disabled, by changing the font color and check box icon.

Thank you very much!

Comment: So, if the checkbox "looks" disable, what makes you think they'll try and click it?

Comment: Haha... And for some reason that had not even occured to me. So what should i do with this super pointless post?

Comment: Having a check box look disabled, but be enabled does not make much sense. Maybe you should change your question to: "How to change color of JCheckBox"

Comment: For any one else looking at this topic i have decided instead to merely uncheck the checkboxes to show they are not being used (which is a much more logical solution). But if you still want to do this you can set the font color to gray by using `CheckBox.setForeground(Color.gray);` And you can look at this link to change the icon of the box: [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CustomizeJCheckBoxicons.htm)

Comment: @ theProgrammer101 - thank you! I fixed the title.

Comment: "*allow the user to see that the check box is not being used*" - that is typically indicated by the checkbox not being checked.

Comment: @theProgrammer101 *"Maybe you should change your question.."* Better to change the entire *approach*.

Comment: @Andrew that's a good point, this question does not make much sense